# Creating Sub-Threads From a Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

In a java program, I spawned one thread other than the main thread, and then spawned another two threads from the original thread I created(two sub threads). In all the cases I used the Runnable interface to create threads. My question is, is there a better way of doing this? Does the performance degrade when you spawn threads recursively?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a parent-child relationship between threads in Java. Once created, they have a life of their own.

Regarding performance, you may want to use an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to control the number of threads created in your application. Too many threads will kill performance for sure. See the [Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class too.

The way you are creating threads is perfectly ok if it is only a few. Otherwise, executor services are the preferred method.

Comment: There are ThreadGroups but those are really only used for organization / naming.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with what you are doing, no performance degradation.  If you had a more complicated program with a large number of threads, you could look for utility classes in `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem creating a few threads this way.

For slower operations like network IO it's even pretty good, you can have quit a lot of threads as they are mostly waiting.

For number crunching threads I'd use an ExecutorService retrieved using [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) with the Runtime.numberOfProcessors() or something like that as the amount of threads. If processing is CPU constrained more threads only make it less efficient.

Also, disk IO tends to be better serial than parallel.

If you have CPU or disk IO constrained processors you can also look at the producer-consumer pattern as described in the [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) javadocs. Your main thread (or threads) create processing or load tasks and dump these on a blocking queue. A fixed amount of worker threads process the items on the queue.